# Amazon AWS for Android not accepts Google token Id, as identity provider

Tags: authentication, amazon-web-services

I acquire the Google tokenId and pass it to the CredentialsProvider instance based on the instructions [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/devguide/identity/external-providers/google/).

```
 String token = AccountUtils.getAuthToken(this);
 Map<String, String> logins = new HashMap<>();
 logins.put("accounts.google.com", token);
 getCredentialsProvider().withLogins(logins);
```

Then I refresh the CredentialsProvider instance by calling below line in an AsyncTask:

```
getCredentialsProvider().refresh();
```

I get no exceptions, I expect too see a new Google Authenticated user in the cognito control panel. But I only get a new unauthenticated user. sigh

I checked that the token I am receiving from Google is just fine and that I have set the clientId in the cognito settings.

Any help is highly appreciated

Answer (score 3):

After 2 days of trying to make it work, and tempted a lot to forget AWS 4ever and run my own server, I was able to find the solution with the help of [this guy](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=625493).

If you follow the Google [instructions](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/start) to integrate sign in, you will receive 2 client ids in step 2 and 4. You need to put first one in your cognito pool and the second one in your app.

Apparently Amazon has mentioned this nowhere in their [documentations](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/devguide/identity/external-providers/google/)